# Change Shell script to replace numbers in a file name with complementary sequence

Tags: bash, shell, file

I have some 160 files, with continuous numbering within the file names, like `abc_1_def.ext` to `uvw_162_yxz.ext`. The numbers were generated in time sequence, unfortunately with the most recent data first, the most ancient data last.
We prefer to rename these files, in proper historical order, that is `abc_162_def.ext` to `uvw_1_yxz.ext`; meaning with incremental numbers in historical sequence. Kind of stack task.

I have tried myself, though I didn't have any good idea to manipulate the numbers. There are plenty of samples with adding a fixed number and likewise. However, not for this kind of LiFo problem.
Appreciate any suggestion!

Comment: As usual, I would separate a complicated problem into separate sub-problems which can be solved independently: First, take your files and bring them into historically correct order. The result of this step should ideally be an array of file names, but if the filenames don't contain newline characters, it could also be a file, holding one filename per line. The second step would be to take the ordered list of names and rename them according to your new naming strategy.

Comment: Is the prefix of each file different like shown  (`abc_`, `uvw_`)?

Comment: you've stated: *`I have tried myself`*;  please update the question with your attempts to address this issue along with the (wrong) results generated by your attempts

Comment: you've stated the files contains numbers between `1` and `162`; are there any gaps in this sequence? if there are gaps ... are you looking to reuse the same set of numbers or are you looking to generate a new set of gap-less numbers; for example, assume you have 2 files with the numbers `1` and `4` (ie, `2` and `3` are missing => a gap), should the new files also be numbered with `1` and `4` or should they be numbred with `1` and `2`?

Comment: No. No gaps in between. No duplicates. Just straight forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making a few assumptions -

```bash
touch foo_{1..20}_bar.ext       # simplified set
shopt -s extglob                # more specific globbing
mkdir hold                      # a place to avoid naming collisions
mv *_+([0-9])_*.ext hold/       # make sure this grabs the right set
declare -i cnt=0                # reinitialize this is you run it again!
lst=( $( printf "%s\n" hold/* | 
           sort -t_ -k2,2rn ) ) # reverse numeric order on the key
for f in "${lst[@]}"
do n="${f#hold/}"               # strip subfolder to move them *back* 
   mv "$f" "./${n/_+([0-9])_/_$((++cnt))_}" # replace/reorder the numbers
done
```

I ran it with an `echo` for this:

```
$: for f in "${lst[@]}"; do n="${f#hold/}"; echo mv "$f" "./${n/_+([0-9])_/_$((++cnt))_}"; done
mv hold/foo_20_bar.ext ./foo_1_bar.ext
mv hold/foo_19_bar.ext ./foo_2_bar.ext
mv hold/foo_18_bar.ext ./foo_3_bar.ext
mv hold/foo_17_bar.ext ./foo_4_bar.ext
mv hold/foo_16_bar.ext ./foo_5_bar.ext
mv hold/foo_15_bar.ext ./foo_6_bar.ext
mv hold/foo_14_bar.ext ./foo_7_bar.ext
mv hold/foo_13_bar.ext ./foo_8_bar.ext
mv hold/foo_12_bar.ext ./foo_9_bar.ext
mv hold/foo_11_bar.ext ./foo_10_bar.ext
mv hold/foo_10_bar.ext ./foo_11_bar.ext
mv hold/foo_9_bar.ext ./foo_12_bar.ext
mv hold/foo_8_bar.ext ./foo_13_bar.ext
mv hold/foo_7_bar.ext ./foo_14_bar.ext
mv hold/foo_6_bar.ext ./foo_15_bar.ext
mv hold/foo_5_bar.ext ./foo_16_bar.ext
mv hold/foo_4_bar.ext ./foo_17_bar.ext
mv hold/foo_3_bar.ext ./foo_18_bar.ext
mv hold/foo_2_bar.ext ./foo_19_bar.ext
mv hold/foo_1_bar.ext ./foo_20_bar.ext
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, that's exactly what I was looking for! - Unfortunately, my reputation is too bad to give you an 'arrow up'. Stupid, this. You deserved it!
What I was mostly missing was the reverse numeric order, for which I had no clue in shell script.
Thanks again!

Comment: This is NO criticism at all, please! Only in case someone finds this great and useful item: It fails, when the file name contains blanks. I only noticed because one person had initially allocated a wrong file name, and that brought a bunch of failures in the subsequent numbers.

Comment: Are you including the quotes? Did you remove the echo, or did you send the output to a file and run that separately? If you're using the output as a script, try it this way: `for f in "${lst[@]}"; do n="${f#hold/}"; echo mv "'$f'" "'./${n/_+([0-9])_/_$((++cnt))_}'"; done`

Comment: Not that I needed it any longer, also because we do not allow blanks in file names anyway. Only since you ask, I left the script almost as given, just adapting to the location of the numbers in the file names:
`lst=( $( printf "%s\n" hold/* | 
        sort -t_ -k 3 -n -r ) ) # reverse numeric order on the key
for f in "${lst[@]}"
do n="${f#hold/}"               # strip subfolder to move them *back* 
   mv "$f" "./${n/2021_+([0-9])_/2021_$((++cnt))_}" # replace/reorder the numbers
done`